# Xamarin binding of Android library(AAR)

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-binding

I want to use https://www.dsphotoeditor.com/ library in xamarin Android. For that I have created a binding project. I know how to create binding, I have already do it for sinch library. But for https://www.dsphotoeditor.com/, I am not able to solve some error. I have updated its metdata.xml file with following content

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.focusablelinearlayout']" name="managedName">BindingFocusablelinearlayout</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.imagebrushview']" name="managedName">BindingImagebrushview</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.stickerview']" name="managedName">BindingStickerview</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.touchimageview']" name="managedName">BindingTouchimageview</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.touchimageview']/class[@name='TouchImageView']/method[@name='onConfigurationChanged' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.content.res.Configuration']]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.touchimageview']/class[@name='TouchImageView']/method[@name='onRestoreInstanceState' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.os.Parcelable']]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
   <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.touchimageview']/class[@name='TouchImageView']/method[@name='onSaveInstanceState' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview']/class[@name='CropImageView']/method[@name='onDraw' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.graphics.Canvas']]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview']/class[@name='CropImageView']/method[@name='onRestoreInstanceState' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='android.os.Parcelable']]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
  <attr path="/api/package[@name='com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview']/class[@name='CropImageView']/method[@name='onSaveInstanceState' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">protected</attr>
```

First to 4th line in above mentioned XML is added because to remove error

> **"Namespace path cannot have classname. Name voilation error"**

5th to 10th lines added to make **class protected(Reason:By default .Net making public classes so it cause issues in overriding java protected methods)**

Above method metadata helps to fix some error but it still have many error .Error are given below

> Class BindingImagebrushview.ImageBrushView has unknown base type
>   com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.a.c.
>
> Unknown return type com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.a in
>   method A in managed type
>   Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.
>         Unknown parameter type com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.b.b in method A in managed
>   type Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.
>
> Unknown parameter type
>   com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.CropImageView.a in method A in
>   managed type Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.
>
> Unknown parameter type
>   com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.CropImageView.a in method
>   SetCropMode in managed type
>   Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.
>
> Unknown parameter type
>   com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.CropImageView.c in method
>   SetGuideShowMode in managed type
>   Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.
>         Unknown parameter type com.dsphotoeditor.sdk.ui.simplecropview.CropImageView.c in method
>   SetHandleShowMode in managed type
>   Com.Dsphotoeditor.Sdk.UI.Simplecropview.CropImageView.

Working Android code of this library https://drive.google.com/open?id=1msStp0MdaGVY8QVXl8ZVpzLrqXoJQoMG

Comment: Typo: `metdata.xml` instead of `metadata.xml`

Comment: Your error message is unique in the world: you're the first human being seeing it: https://www.google.com/search?q="Name+voilation+error"